# How to download and install Feb 2013 patch?

Tags: planetside-2

I have not played Planetside 2 for a while. I heard there was a big patch. I don't know how to download it.

I open the game and get this launch screen. From there nothing happens. Can't see I am able to download a patch. Can't see that it is downloading a patch. Cant see how to launch the game that may download the patch.

I also went to the website and there was nothing blazingly obvious that there was a patch to download from there.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to download the installer and run the repair/reinstall option. Once I did that, the launcher came up again and this time it started downloading the patch.